# how to store touchid fingerprint data in ios 10 swift 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I am trying to store user's touchid for unlocking an app.But I am facing problems in storing the user's touch id data.Can someone tell me how to store it in our xcode.
Here's the link address of app of touch id on which i am working.
Any help for this?

Comment: Tell us a bit more. What exactly are you trying to do? What problem do you habe? Errors?

Comment: what I am trying to do is i m creating a password to log in through myApp either by touch id or by pin.So,when the user register through touchid that touch id should save somewhere..how to make that thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not able to store user's touchid. I suggest reading one of the many tutorials available. E.g. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-integrating-touch-id--cms-21949

Comment: thnku sir...Helped me a lot