# Use TouchID to add fingerprints that are only used within the app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

The idea is that when the app launches, two people scan their fingers. Later, when one of those people uses TouchID, something happens. I know how to use TouchId to verify the owner of the phone, but I can't find any info on temporary storing scanned prints and using them for purposes other than verifying the owner.

Can this be done? If yes, can someone point me in the right direction of implementing this.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: This question answered before<br>
[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383774/how-to-store-touchid-fingerprint-data-in-ios-10-swift-3)

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I'm pretty sure that it can't be accomplished

Comment: Sorry @arash, i didnt find that answer when searching 

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible, you cannot store scanned prints in the APP even though you cannot access information about fingerprints which have already been saved in the device by owner as Apple does not provide any APIs. All you can do is to verify the owner of the device that you have mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 2):

That is not posible.

You can only request for user authentication through biometrics, and Apple handles everything through the LocalAuthentication Framework.

Here is a use case example:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication